# Does Windows 8 allow multiboot when installing from a mounted ISO?

Tags: multi-boot, windows-8

I just downloaded Windows 8 and am itching to install it. The installation says it will clean everything out. I assume (hope) that it only means I cannot transfer settings from my current OS and that I will be able to multiboot like any other normal OS but I'm not sure.

I'm installing by mounting the ISO since this computer doesn't have any DVD.

**Does Windows 8 support multibooting?** Specically together with windows 7, without any special "put in this dvd and run this command" stuff.

Comment: If you install to a separate partition, it _should_ be fine. I'm still waiting for it to download though, so I don't want to answer saying it'll for-sure work the way you expect it to until I get a chance to try myself.

Comment: "Should" and "will" are too different for me to give it a spin "now". Have to wait until I wont need to work I guess :)

Comment: installing W8 now, will let you know soon :)

Comment: Are you installing from inside windows7? :) (heres to hoping)

Comment: YES. Was able to get the ISO to run from W7 by using PowerISO instead of MagicISO ... more to come

Comment: wow, that was fun :) i hoped W8 would ask me to select a partition to install it on, but it just went ahead and used my C drive ... I have to say, W8 looks pretty cool, too bad I'd have to reinstall all my apps.

Comment: That's what I feared. Thanks for being my guinea pig :) Write up a real answer so I can mark it as solved ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **CAN** do a multiboot install **without clearing** anything:

- Download the ISO file from Microsoft.
- Mount the ISO using Daemon Tools, Clone Drive, or similar.

*(This is important. Do not use the autorun installer. The autorun installer only allows you to upgrade your existing Windows installation and will not allow you to install to a separate hard drive or partition.)*

- Navigate to the virtual install disk and **go to the folder called `sources`**.
- Run `setup.exe` and proceed as if installing Windows Vista or Windows 7.

[image]

References:

- *[How To Install Windows 8 From USB Key](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/09/14/how-to-install-windows-8-from-usb-key/)*
- *[Installing Windows 8 without bootable media](http://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/kf7ax/installing_windows_8_without_bootable_media/)*

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE:**

1. Yes, Windows 8 supports dual boot, ***but*** you have to install it on another partition from **bootable media** (such as DVD or USB drive).
2. **Do NOT install Windows 8 from inside your OS by mounting the ISO**, it will install over your primary partition WITHOUT giving you any other option (and without explicitly telling you what's going to happen).

**UPDATE 2:**

Windows 8 kept my Windows 7 install in (Windows.old). I'll try to revert back to it tonight as per [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933168). I'll report the results once I try this.

**ORIGINAL:**

I first wanted to install Windows 8 on a virtual machine, but I was unable to due to a lack of VT support by my processor ([E4400](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_2_microprocessors#Core_2_Duo)). Then I've decided to install it on a separate partition, so I can dual-boot. I've mounted the ISO with [MagicISO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagicISO), but it kept crashing on me, this problem was solved by using [PowerISO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerISO).

Once I mounted the ISO and fired it up, I clicked through a simple wizard, hoping that when the install files get dumped in the `temp` directory and computer restarts, the install will ask me to pick a partition.

Was I wrong on that one; the Windows 8 install went ahead and used my primary partition for Windows 8 install (not a big deal since I keep all my data on a separate partition).

@Journeyman Geek mentioned Advanced Partitioning option, but I didn't see it when I ran the setup.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I had to read it twice and still can't believe it! Does this *fantastic thing* really overwrite the data without warning?

Comment: @maartinus: read my update

Comment: Better, but still: Any program must never ever destroy user's data (unless explicitly told to), otherwise it's just...

Comment: It says it will "clear everything" which is what got me to ask her in the first place. It even gives you a "choice" with one option "Clear everything"

Comment: @Richard: while it says "Clear Everything" i would assume it would ask WHERE to clear it from. Just saying.

Comment: I know, but those kinda things you cant ask of a developer preview where they probably spent most off the time making sure developers could start making apps and what-not. I can guarantee you that the full version will be 100% UAC annoying á la microsoft :)

Answer (score 2):

Yup. Just point [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) to the Windows 8 partition, and it wakes up like a little baby.

So [BCDedit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_startup_process#Boot_Configuration_Data) works. But I haven't gotten [EasyBCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyBCD) to work for some reason.

Comment: Not everyone uses GRUB as their bootload. Can you expand your answer to include some more info on how multiboot might work in this scenario?

Comment: Oh oops. It looks like the same bootloader.  I'll have to verify.