# Is it possible to dual boot Windows XP and Windows 8 Developer Preview?

Tags: windows-xp, multi-boot, windows-8-preview

According to [the Windows 8 Developer Preview download page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516), you can upgrade Vista or 7 to 8DP if you don't want the developer tools. But you must do a clean install if you had XP, regardless of if you want the tools or not.

So it gave me an idea that I'd just like to ask about: is it possible to dual-boot my XP laptop to make it run XP and 8DP, or do I need to do a clean install over XP?

(Note: I want to avoid virtualization because I don't like it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create 2 partitions and install XP onto the first and 8DP onto the second.
I think you will have to do 8 second so the bootloader recognises the older version of Windows. Then when you boot up you will be able to select which OS you boot from.

UPDATE: (Taken from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/335355/does-windows-8-developer-preview-64bit-allow-multiboot-when-installing-from-a-mou) question)
 1.
Yes, W8 supports dual boot, BUT you have to install it on another partition from bootable media (such as DVD or USB drive).

2.
Do NOT install W8 from inside your OS by mounting the ISO, it will install over your primary partition WITHOUT giving you any other option (and without explicitly telling you what's going to happen).

Comment: Please tell me if I'm wrong: I have to burn the ISO to a DVD, then I will reboot my PC, load the disc in, then when I'm asked about partitions, opt to resize my XP partition, create a new partition for 8 and choose that for the system files to go to.

Comment: I'd use a tool like GParted to create the partition before install. Otherwise you're there.

Comment: Yeah, definitely make the partitions before.

Comment: @Joe There is a new bootloader with Windows 8 Preview according to this question [How should I get my bootloader working for my ubuntu, win7 and win8 on vhd?](http://superuser.com/questions/336158/how-should-i-get-my-bootloader-working-for-my-ubuntu-win7-and-win8-on-vhd) nice! I think it will solve the problem of which OS to install first.

Answer (score 1):

You **CAN** do a multiboot Install **without clearing** anything

- Download the ISO file from Microsoft.
- Mount the ISO using Daemon Tools, Clone Drive, or similar.

*(This is important. Do not use the autorun installer. The autorun installer only allows you to upgrade your existing Windows installation and will not allow you to install to a separate hard drive or partition.)*

- Navigate to the virtual install disc and **go to the folder called `sources`**.
- Run `setup.exe` and proceed as if installing Windows Vista or 7.

[image]

Links:
http://www.ghacks.net/2011/09/14/how-to-install-windows-8-from-usb-key/
http://techspyre.com/how-to-directly-install-windows-8-without-cd-dvd-or-usb/
http://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/kf7ax/installing_windows_8_without_bootable_media/

Comment: This sounds like a great method, however will the setup from the x64 ISO run on 32-bit XP?

Comment: @adam: I think x64 applications do not run on 32 bit operating systems. If you are able to run the autorun installer, you should be able to run above mentioned setup too.

Comment: @adam - You would be limited to installing a 32-bit version of Windows 8 unless you migrated your XP installation to x64.  At least using this mehtod.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, XP x64 hasn't had an update since Service Pack 2, so I'm going to dual-boot 7 and 8 x64 instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [EasyBCD 2.1](http://www.fileserve.com/file/HWav8tb/EasyBCD%202.1.exe) program.