# How do I shutdown / restart Windows 8 preview?

Tags: shutdown, windows-8-preview

Just installed Windows 8 Preview, and can't figure out how to get to Shutdown/Restart option in the Start menu.

Clicking on start menu brings up the "Start Screen", but Shutdown/Restart options are not there.

Had to use command prompt to shut my box down.

Ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have a few options:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>, then press the On/Off button, in the bottom right corner.
- Press the hardware power button your computer
- **Log out**, and on the log-in screen you'll see the power options.
- When on the desktop - hover over the start button, press the 'power' button.
- Press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and use the command: *shutdown.exe -f -s*
- On the desktop, minimize all windows and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: "Press the hardware power button your computer" ??? what is the world coming to :)

Comment: @rm it's a pretty valid route these days. Unless you're holding the power button it can perform a safe shutdown, lock, hibernate - whatever you have it set to.

Comment: @rm. Many motherboards these day support a soft poweroff, where it sends a signal to the OS that the powerswitch was hit.  For example, at work, you have to hold the power switch for four seconds to do a traditional "pull the plug" power off.

Answer (score 22):

Its under Settings in the Start Menu (you need to hover over the lower left corner of the Start Button to get the menu with settings, NOT click it).

Or, alternatively, you can hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to bring up the settings panel.

[image: Settings/Power-down Screenshot]

Comment: @Moab, see http://superuser.com/questions/335423/is-it-possible-to-dual-boot-windows-xp-and-windows-8-developer-preview. Would hopefully work for W7/W8DP too.

Comment: +1, this is the intended way for most people to do it (comparable to selecting it off the start menu in older versions)

Comment: @Moab: If you "Change Defaults" to your Windows 7, it goes back to the old boot loader, so you can boot both. (You can do this when pressing F8 on booting, and selecting a different OS.)

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Alt + Del, then press the On/Off button. Lower right corner.

Answer (score 1):

From [this source](http://www.geek.com/articles/geek-pick/how-to-get-a-windows-7-start-menu-in-windows-8-20110914/):

```
If you want to change the Windows 8 start menu  back to the Windows 7 version, here’s what you need to do:

    Launch the registry editor (win+r > regedit >enter)
    Drill down to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
    Double-click on RPEnabled
    Change the value from 1 to  (zero)
    Tap enter or click OK

The change will take place immediately — just tap the Windows key on your keyboard twice to try it out (the first press will slide the Metro start screen back into view).
Once you make the change, the trademark Windows 8 start screen will no longer appear after you log in. Instead, you’ll be greeted by an interface that looks almost exactly like your existing Windows 7 desktop — the only real difference being the squared-off window borders on your applications. Whether the menu makes it as an option in the final Windows 8 release is unknown, but I’m sure Microsoft will be getting plenty of feedback about its removal.
```

Comment: No longer works in Consumer Preview

Answer (score 0):

Press the power button on your pc case/laptop.