# How should I get my bootloader working for my Ubuntu, Windows 7 and Windows 8 on VHD?

Tags: ubuntu, bootloader, windows-8-preview, boot-to-vhd

I have a dual-boot system - 2 partitions - 1 Windows 7 and 1 Ubuntu 11.04 - using the Windows 7 boot-loader, with the Ubuntu boot option added via [EasyBCD](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml&rct=j&q=easybcd&ei=kXJyTuTAIMal8QOntYGaCg&usg=AFQjCNGhURuJ2XEQ42MplrfWon2L3Up7gw&cad=rja).

I also installed the Windows 8 preview on a VHD (as of [Hanselman's instructions here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8DeveloperPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx).)

The Windows 8 boot-loader has overwritten the Windows 7 bootloader. Now I can't boot into my Ubuntu partition.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

In the (excellent) new Windows 8 Preview boot manager, there is an advanced option to *Use another operating system*:

[image]

I selected this, then chose Windows 7. It then rebooted and gave me back my original Windows 7 boot manager (with my Ubuntu choice).

The cherry on the icing was that the Windows 8 choice had been added in automatically for me!

Now I just get one boot screen with the three choices:

- Windows Developer Preview
- Windows 7
- Ubuntu