# Which virtual machine software is preferable for running Windows 8 Developer Preview?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, windows-8-preview

I want to [preview Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516) and decided to install it on a virtual machine as I don't want to format an existing partition.

Installing Windows 8 by mounting the `.iso` [results in the primary partition getting formated](https://superuser.com/questions/335355/does-windows-8-developer-preview-64bit-allow-multiboot-when-installing-from-a-mou/335387#335387) and losing the current operating system.

Can anyone who has tried installing Windows 8 in a virtual machine suggest which virtual machine is preferable to run  *Windows 8 Developer Preview*  from among the following virtual machine softwares.

- [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)
- [VMWare Server](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/overview.html)
- [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/overview.html)
- [Microsoft Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/)

**Edit:**
It is not necessary to restrict to the above list, I would like to know about any other virtualization software available.

Comment: Thank you for the answers I will try installing it on the latest version which seem to be `VirtualBox 4.1.2`

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I'm running a vhd: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8DeveloperPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say that my favourite has to be VMware Workstation. However, restricting it to just your list:

- **VirtualBox**
  It works fine with the latest version. Follow [this guide](http://www.sysprobs.com/guide-install-windows-8-virtualbox) for a walk through on how to do it.
- **VMware Server**
  I can't find anywhere that specifically says no, nor I do have a way to test it, but I highly doubt it can; if it could I wouldn't like to use it. Remember that Windows 8 is heavily graphically accelerated - this is completely against what VMware Server is good at!
- **VMware Workstation**
  If you upgrade to the latest version (8.0.0 Build 471780) - released today as part of the Workstation 8 release - it can run Windows 8 fine.
- **Microsoft Virtual PC**
  Currently cannot run Windows 8; HAL error.

Answer (score 7):

I have successfully installed the Windows 8 Developer Preview in a VirtualBox (4.1.0) Virtual Machine. You cannot, however, install the Guest Additions as it errors with:

> This version of Windows is not supported.

You therefore won't get shared folders, mouse pointer integration, etc. The graphics driver seems to be okay, though, and I can get it to 1280x1024 no problem. I've not tried playing videos or any of the included games.

I'd recommend running it with at least 1GB RAM. A clean install on a dynamic 120GB Virtual Hard Disk takes around ~6.3GB.

Comment: The guest additions I don't think is a virtualization error, but rather a restriction on the dev build: [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516)

Comment: You can install the guest additions by running the installer in Compatibility Mode for Windows 7. It doesn't work perfectly though.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Windows 8 blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006075202/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/16/running-windows-8-developer-preview-in-a-virtual-environment.aspx) posted 9/16:

> Functional:
>
> - Hyper-V in Windows 8 Developer Preview
> - Hyper-V in Windows Server 2008 R2
> - VMware Workstation 8.0 for Windows
> - VirtualBox 4.1.2 for Windows
>
> Non-functional:
>
> - Microsoft Virtual PC (all versions)
> - Microsoft Virtual Server (all versions)
> - Windows 7 XP Mode
> - VMWare Workstation 7.x or older

Answer (score 3):

I installed it with no problems using Hyper-V on Windows Server 2008 R2.  I wasn't able to use RemoteFX 3D Video Adapter, however.  I gave it 8 GB of RAM and 120 GB hard drive space.  The RAM was probably overkill, but I wanted to have fun with it.

Answer (score 0):

Running Windows 8 Developer Preview on [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) Desktop 6.

It works fine on the whole but there are graphics problems when you install parallel tools.
There is a workaround to this which you can find [here](http://kb.parallels.com/112317).
This also has a few graphical limitations but will resolve the blank screen issues that you get after installing parallel tools.

I decided not to install Parallel Tools and have been using Windows 8 Developer Preview non stop for 5 days now with very little problems.

One problem I am having however is after ejecting a disc from the D drive, the D drive still thinks the disc is in the drive and will not recognize any other discs I insert.
This is a pain when trying to install multiple software from discs. I have to restart Windows 8 Developer Preview to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In [Scott Hanselman's blog on this topic](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToGuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8ConsumerPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx), he has an interesting virtual approach. Instead of using a virtual machine inside of your booted machine, he creates a virtual drive (VHD) and configures a dual boot with an option to boot off the VHD. He has instructions and links on the blog article for both the consumer and developers win8 versions.