# How can I run a Virtual Machine in Windows 8 Developer Preview?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualization, windows-8-preview

Since having issues [installing Ubuntu side-by-side with Windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76004/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-11-10-alongside-windows-8-dev-preview), I thought I'd try running Ubuntu in a VM instead. However, VMWare player has no love for Windows 8 yet (invalid VM86 or something similar), and AFAIK the [promised hypervisor](http://virtualization.info/en/news/2011/09/microsoft-confirms-its-client-hypervisor-for-windows-8.html) options are not currently available for playing with.

So: Are there any VM hosts that *do* work in Windows 8 Developer Preview at this point? (specifically for running Ubuntu)

Alternatively, does Wubi work on Windows 8? It seems not; from Wubi:

> An error occurred:
>
> 'WindowsBackend' object has no attribute 'iso_path'

Comment: On a related note, [this mentions](http://superuser.com/q/335508/4377) which Virtualization software work with Windows 8 as guests, perhaps you should try them?

Comment: @Sathya (I removed my earlier response) noted, and indeed related - but this is windows-8 as the host

Comment: Did you try turning Hyper-V on? http://blog.concurrency.com/infrastructure/how-to-enable-hyper-v-on-windows-8-developer-preview/

Comment: @todda I couldn't find that; that *might* indeed be the answer here. I'll look

Comment: @MarcGravell Have a look at this link: http://www.winrumors.com/microsoft-provides-virtualization-recommendations-for-windows-8-developer-preview/ they may give you more direction. You should be able to get access to the Hyper-V preview

Comment: And if all that fails, I'd (personally) try VirtualBox rather than VMware.

Comment: @todda.speot.is apparently my CPU lacks 2nd-level address translation so hyper-V is not an option. I'll try VirtualBox. I think you should add both of those in an answer, personally.

Comment: VirtualBox works great for me, I currently have the Win8 preview and XUbuntu (and Fedora 15) in it and haven't had any problems yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per todda.speot.is's comments, VirtualBox  seems to be my best option here. In many cases, enabling Hyper-V on the dev-8 might be even more direct, but in my case my CPU does not support that. I now have a working Ubuntu install as a VM.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a tutorial here, it's a little hard to follow and the author seems to take for granted what we do and do not know, but in spite of that I think this will answer your questions:

[How to Install Ubuntu](http://www.howtowindows.com/2011/install-ubuntu-in-windows-with-wubi-video/)

Comment: In windows 7, it may well have done - however, under windows 8 the wubi installer simply fails

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V is available in the Windows 8 developer preview. You have open "Programs and Features" (Go to search, then "Settings", then write "Programs and features"). Once there, click on "Turn windows features on or off" and check Hyper-V.
I have not tested Ubuntu with Hyper-V, so I don't know if it is a "supported scenario".

Comment: Sorry... I have just seen your comment that your processor is not supported by Hyper-V... I will not erase my answer as it may be usefull for someone else...

Comment: I agree - leave it here; it could help others