# Windows 8 64bit on Virtualbox installation freezes, throws error

Tags: windows-8-preview, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which virtual machine software is preferable for running Windows 8 Developer Preview?](https://superuser.com/questions/335508/which-virtual-machine-software-is-preferable-for-running-windows-8-developer-pre)

I am having troubles with installing Windows 8 on Virtualbox - I installed it once, but had to remove it and now I am trying again. However this time it freezes on

> Expanding Windows Files 99%

I have tried all options, but to no avail. I have installed other VM's, like Vista, Windows 7, Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise, etc.

After a lot of waiting the installation finishes with an error

> 0x8007045D

I saw this error the second time I installed Windows 2008; however i just tried one more time and everything completed successfully. With Windows 8 I tried 5 or 6 times and it is always the same.

I restarted my computer, repaired and reinstalled Virtualbox, tried playing with the options of the VM (not just randomly, I followed a tutorial), I burnt a new disk and tried directly with the iso - always the same problem and I am still not able to install it.

Comment: Try to download the ISO again, it could be corrupted.

Comment: I installed the Windows twice, using the same iso. One of these two times was on Virtualbox (this is mentioned in my post). Burning the iso again and using the iso itself did not work either.

Comment: See this [Which virtual machine software is preferable for running Windows 8 Developer Preview?](http://superuser.com/q/335508)