# Install Windows 8 developer preview on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-8-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Windows 8 using ISO from XP](https://superuser.com/questions/336291/install-windows-8-using-iso-from-xp)

I have an old XP machine and I want to try Windows 8 on that?

Is it possible to install Windows 8 developer preview on Windows XP?